# jQuery replace html of h1 tag when click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do what seems to be a simple task but I can't seem to figure it out . I'm replacing the contents of a  tag using jquery .html method. I want to get it changed when I click on a button and it does change but then immediately returns back to its original value, I cannot understand why is that ? I tried .replaceWith as well and it has the same effect. Any ideas?

Here is the html part:

```
...
  <div class="container">
<h1 id="putname">Hello</h1>        
</div>
```

Submit

...

Here is the java script

```
 <script>
$("#btn1").click(function(){
var name = $("#inputname").val();
$("#putname").html("<p> text </p>");
alert ("hello" + name); }); 
</script>
```

I added alert just to demonstrate that it works and you can see html is being replaced but then it switches back to its original value...

Thanks

Comment: If you have a problem with your code, then it's definitely not the part of the code you posted. [**It does work just fine**](http://jsfiddle.net/egvbwy3v/)

Comment: Its better we see all the HTML code.

Comment: Well my guess is btn1 is a submit button and the form submits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you have a submit button that submits the page, so you need to cancel the submission or prevent the default action of the button.

```
$("#btn1").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```